# SQL count hour for each date of a datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a subquery which returns just one column with a datetime type:

```
LOG_DATE
---------------------
2014-06-30 08:15:00
2014-07-01 08:00:00
2014-07-01 08:45:00
2014-07-01 10:00:00
2014-07-01 13:00:00
2014-07-01 14:00:00
2014-07-01 14:30:00
2014-07-01 14:55:00
2014-07-02 08:10:00
2014-07-02 09:00:00
2014-07-02 09:10:00
2014-07-02 09:25:00
2014-07-02 09:40:00
2014-07-02 10:10:00
```

I'm trying to write a script using this subquery which should return:

```
DATE        |  HOUR      |  TOTAL
----------------------------------
2014-06-30  |  08:00:00  |  1
2014-07-01  |  08:00:00  |  2
2014-07-01  |  10:00:00  |  1
2014-07-01  |  13:00:00  |  1
2014-07-01  |  14:00:00  |  3
2014-07-02  |  08:00:00  |  1
2014-07-02  |  09:00:00  |  4
2014-07-02  |  10:00:00  |  1
```

Can someone help me how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LOG_DATE, 120), CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), LOG_DATE, 108)+':00:00', COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LOG_DATE, 120), CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), LOG_DATE, 108)+':00:00'
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LOG_DATE, 120), CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), LOG_DATE, 108)+':00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,LOG_DATE) [DATE],
       DATEPART(HOUR,LOG_DATE) [HOUR],
       COUNT(*) TOTAL
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,LOG_DATE),
         DATEPART(HOUR,LOG_DATE)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,LOG_DATE),
         DATEPART(HOUR,LOG_DATE)
```

The results are:

```
╔════════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║    DATE    ║ HOUR ║ TOTAL ║
╠════════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 2014-06-30 ║    8 ║     1 ║
║ 2014-07-01 ║    8 ║     2 ║
║ 2014-07-01 ║   10 ║     1 ║
║ 2014-07-01 ║   13 ║     1 ║
║ 2014-07-01 ║   14 ║     3 ║
║ 2014-07-02 ║    8 ║     1 ║
║ 2014-07-02 ║    9 ║     4 ║
║ 2014-07-02 ║   10 ║     1 ║
╚════════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

And [**here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea14e/3) a sqlfiddle with a demo of it.

Comment: Thanks Lamak, both scripts, JiggsJedi's and yours worked fine. If I could mark both answers as accepted, I would do it.